# Задержка Javascript

Tags: php, html

У меня на сайте почему-то задерживаются скрипты *Javascript*.

Проблема в том, что я разделил шаблон на:

```
Header.php(хидер)
Head.php(инклуд нужных css,script)
Footer.php(футер,инклуд и выполнение javascript).
```

Например, у меня есть страница `Index.php`. В конце этой страницы есть мини-слайдер. Почему-то выполнение скрипта задерживается на секунду и картинки в слайдере становятся огромными, и стоят не по порядку.

Я думаю, проблема в том, что скрипт выполняется отдельно от файла, то есть в `footer.php`.

Так как же устранить эту задержку?

Comment: Нет, не отдельно. Файл браузеру отдаётся целиком. Проблема в отрисовке. Любой JS должен выполнятся минимум после готовности документа. Проверка на готовность зависит от того, что вы используете. У jQuery, например, есть для этого функция готовая. Полагаю проблема в этом.

Comment: по описанию похоже что CSS подгружается после скрипта